# Sign an Android app with Python for Android (Buildozer)

Tags: android, python, apk

i'm using [Buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer) to compile Python scripts to Android executable files (.apk).

But I've got a problem : I can't run them on Android (I have installed it in a virtual machine). I have found that I need to sign the app to be able to run it. So, how do I sign my application ? I'm using GNU/Linux.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered comprehensively by Ben Rousch at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/5-G7wkbHb_k

He said:

> In general, the steps are:
>
> ```
>    1 Generate Keystore (once)
>    2 Create Release APK
>    3 Sign APK
>    4 Zip-align APK
> ```

Ben also posted example terminal commands for the workflow at the above link.

Hope that helps