# Can't build unassigned release APK with buildozer android_new realease

Tags: android, python, ant, kivy, buildozer

I can't build unassigned release APK with buildozer android_new release. I have searched the web for a solution but I can't just find one. I came across this https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/363, but no success.

However, I can build the DEBUG APK with buildozer android_new debug. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443740/sign-an-android-app-with-python-for-android-buildozer) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/5-G7wkbHb_k) and also [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/5-G7wkbHb_k), the steps are to

1. Generate Keystore (once)
2. Create Release APK
3. Sign APK
4. Zip-align APK